# Trying to avoid background size repetition using SASS

Tags: css, sass, background-size

I'm using `background-size` a lot throughout my SASS, repeating the declaration every time I need to use it.

Ideally i'd like to write the declaration once with a unique class and extend it elsewhere. I've tried something below, which doesn't work. `background-size` only seems to work when you include it in the same ruleset.

The main reason behind this is to reduce the CSS output.

Here's what I would normally write which works:

```
.banner { 

    &.one {
        background: url(link-to-img-1.jpg) no-repeat 0 0;
        background-size: 500px auto;
    }

    &.two {
        background: url(link-to-img-2.jpg) no-repeat 0 0;
        background-size: 500px auto;
    }

}
```

Here's what I would like to write which doesn't work:

```
%background-size {
    background-size: 500px auto;
}
.banner { 

    &.one {
        background: url(link-to-img-1.jpg) no-repeat 0 0;
        @extend %background-size;
    }

    &.two {
        background: url(link-to-img-2.jpg) no-repeat 0 0;
        @extend %background-size;
    }

}
```

Is this possible? I've set up a pen to illustrate the problem: http://codepen.io/abbasinho/pen/ZYaGJb

Comment: if you paste your sass code into sassmeister it works as expected

Comment: I set up a quick pen to illustrate: http://codepen.io/abbasinho/pen/ZYaGJb in a working environment it doesn't seem to work. Checking dev tools there's a line through the background-size declaration.

Comment: Try reading the compiled CSS.  The answer is obvious if you think about it.

Comment: @cimmanon Maybe so but I'm not seeing it. Will review.

Comment: @cimmanon *So it likes riddles, precioussss...*

Comment: Also related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28190749/scss-placeholders-compiled-in-wrong-order